# Reading an INI file using monads

Tags: haskell

I am a trying to read an INI file with haskell using monads.

Here is my code :

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Ini

main = do
    config <- readIniFile "configs/config.ini"
    port <- (config >>= lookupValue "NETWORK" "port")
    port >>= putStrLn
```

In my limited understanding, `config` and `port` would be of type [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html). How can use an `Either` value with an `IO` action

Comment: Do you know how to use an `Either` value _without_ an `IO` action?

Comment: I tried this using `case of` syntax as highlighted here : https://pastebin.com/nquCFvck and it seems to work . Now trying use `bind` for learning purposes

Comment: No, that's the (or rather: a) right solution. You could use the `either` or `fromRight` functions instead, but I don't think that would be a significant improvement. Note that you don't need to keep nesting like that if you have the `Left` branch terminate the program (with an error or an exception) and the right branch return the value.

Comment: You can't use bind for this: roughly, bind takes something of out its monadic context if that is then re-inserted in the same monadic context. You can't take something out of `Either a` and put it in `IO` with bind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's more than one monad involved, you could use a *monad transformer*. While you'd expect the `Either` monad transformer to be called `EitherT`, it is, for various reasons, called `ExceptT`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Ini

main = runExceptT $ do
  config <- ExceptT $ readIniFile "./config.ini"
  port <- ExceptT $ return $ lookupValue "NETWORK" "port" config
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ show port
```

By doing various lifting, `config` in the above code example is an `Ini` value, and `port` is a `Text` value.

When all operations succeed, the program prints the `port` value, but if one of the operations fail, nothing happens.

Comment: Speaking of “various reasons”, I’ll add that you may see older code using `ErrorT`, which has a spurious `Error` constraint, or `EitherT` from (older versions of?) `either`, but `ExceptT` is the right choice nowadays for an `Either` transformer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different monads involved. `readIniFile` returns an `IO (Either String Ini)` value, which means `config` has type `Either String Ini`. With in *this* `do` expression, you cannot extract the `Text` value from the `Either String Text` value returned by `config >>= lookupValue "NETWORK" "port"`. Instead, use `either` to return a default value should the lookup fail, or extract the port if the lookup succeeds.

```
getPort :: Ini -> Either String Text
getPort cfg = let result = lookupValue "NETWORK" "port" cfg
              in case result of
                    Left "Couldn't find key: port" -> Right "0"
                    otherwise -> result

 main = do
  config <- readIniFile "configs/config.ini"
  -- You could probably do better than just raise an error
  let port = either error id (config >>= getPort)
  putStrLn (unpack port)
```

Comment: Since this just ignores the error message that `lookupValue` might return, you could also probably use `fromRight "0" (config >>= ...)`. (I *think* that requires importing `Data.Either` where `either` does not, but I cannot confirm at the moment.)

Comment: I wonder if a nested `do` and continued use of `<-` would let the code avoid the `>>=` and prevent it from ignoring the config reading errors, if any.

Comment: @9000 Probably not without introducing monad transformers in a way that would be less clear than the current code.

Comment: Yeah, the problem in this case is that's doing two things at once, which is great for an example but not so great in "real" code - a config value not being present is usually not an error (unless it's something where sensible default values genuinely do not exist), but you definitely want to treat syntax errors in a config files as errors.

Comment: Is `Either` really a monad?

Comment: @bipll `Either` is not, but `Either String` is.

Comment: @Cubic Good point; I'll update with a helper function that distinguishes between a missing `port` key and other errors.